# android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to RSAPrivateKey

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, certificate, digital-signature

```
  KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this.getActivity(), new KeyChainAliasCallback() {
    @Override
    public void alias(String alias) {
      if (alias != null) {
        try {
          Certificate[] certificateChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(getContext(), alias);
          PrivateKey privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(getContext(), alias);
          
          Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
          sig.initSign(privateKey);
          sig.update(hashDocument);

                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance                                                                                                   at com.sign.moon.TokenCertificatePlugin$2.alias(TokenCertificatePlugin.java:322)
```

When I call `sig.initSign(privateKey);` I get the exception `android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to RSAPrivateKey`.

Someone has been the same? I am using a real device with a digital certificate installed

`RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;`
tried to instantiate but without success.
In addition to

```
Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
```

Comment: have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/32400689/150978?